# How do I add an ng-click to an element?

Tags: angularjs

I have an HTML element that I cannot directly make changes to.

How would I add an ng-click event to it?

E.g.

```
<div id="myDiv"><img src="my/img/src/jpg"/></div>
```

How would I add an ng-click to the div? Jquery or vanilla JS answers, please.

Comment: You shouldn't use angular *on top* of something (like jQuery), but the other way round.

Comment: Is the document in AngularJS? Does the element have a controller? You may be better off using jQuery's `click()`

Comment: Yes, this document is in Angular. That's why I'm using ng-click! :) And, yes, I am using a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I worked out that, as the element is being provided by a service, it doesn't exist on page load, so I have to try another way to do this.

The answer, in other circumstances, would be:

```
$("#myDiv").attr("ng-click", "myFunction()");
$compile($("#myDiv"))($scope);
```

Just make sure your element exists, when you try to add something to it!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not restricted to using an **ID** on your element (...if you could use a class instead), then you could write a directive to bind the click handler.

You would write the directive to restrict it to that class:

```
<div class="myClass"><img src="my/img/src/jpg"/></div>

angular.module('myModule', [])
    .directive('myClass', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'C', // <-- restrict to classname
            link: function (scope, el) {
                el.on('click', function () {
                    // do stuff
                })
            }
        };
    })
```

This would bind a click to any element with `myClass` added to it.